# How to connect node.js running in zeit with postgresql?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, vercel

There is node.js code(builder `@now/node`) deployed to zeit. Now I want to connect it to PostgreSQL.
This seems to be a very common scenario, yet I can't find learning material that is good enough.
The problem is there are quite a few things to configure here:

1. PostgreSQL instance. (I chose AWS RDS free teir)
2. Security group's inbound connection should cover ips to which zeit is deployed
3. zeit deployment should have the right certificate for establishing ssl connection

Is there something missing here? Is there a good instruction on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guide to connect with mysql. I know it's not PostgreSQL but it should be pretty familiar: https://zeit.co/guides/deploying-next-and-mysql-with-now/

I am connecting my app to a MongoDB instance and it's pretty similar as well.

Comment: Anything similar to `serverless-mysql` but for Postgres?

Comment: for Postgres, maybe, you can use `pgbouncer`